# why the code not add a label in this manual inputbox code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i want to make a popup box / inputbox but visual studio dont have it, so i found a code in stackoverflow and i want add label in that code, but the label not showed up while i run it.

```cs
private static DialogResult ShowInputDialog(ref string input)
{
    System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(500, 300);
    Form inputBox = new Form();

    System.Windows.Forms.Label label = new Label();
    label.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width - 10, 23);
    label.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 50);
    label.Text = "masukkan nilai elemen array" + bb;




    inputBox.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
    inputBox.ClientSize = size;
    inputBox.Text = "WindowsApplication1";

    System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(size.Width - 10, 23);
    textBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(5, 260);
    textBox.Text = input;
    inputBox.Controls.Add(textBox);

    Button okButton = new Button();
    okButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
    okButton.Name = "okButton";
    okButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    okButton.Text = "&OK";
    okButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80 - 80, 100);
    inputBox.Controls.Add(okButton);

    Button cancelButton = new Button();
    cancelButton.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
    cancelButton.Name = "cancelButton";
    cancelButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    cancelButton.Text = "&Cancel";
    cancelButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(size.Width - 80, 100);
    inputBox.Controls.Add(cancelButton);

    inputBox.AcceptButton = okButton;
    inputBox.CancelButton = cancelButton;

    DialogResult result = inputBox.ShowDialog();
    input = textBox.Text;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: All this is stuff you can do in Visual Studio's visual forms designer. Why are you doing this manually? Just make a new class for your input box.

Comment: @aryads you may miss to add Label control to your inputBox control.

Comment: @Nyerguds thanks, i learned how to link 2 form now

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed to add label to inputBox.
You can add it below

```cs
    label.Text = "masukkan nilai elemen array" + bb;
    inputBox.Controls.Add(label)
```

Sorry, I'am not an expert of winform.

Comment: thanks its solve with adding     inputBox.Controls.Add(label);